# ETL jobs in AWS Glue -- possible to overwrite data?

Tags: amazon-web-services, etl, aws-glue

I am trying to write an AWS Glue ETL job that updates schema based on the most recent schema version.
I know this is not typically desirable behavior, but to minimize the number of output files, is it possible to do the transformations directly on the source data so that the transformed data is then loaded back to the same path?
Or is it possible to delete the data in the source path to then rewrite it to the same destination?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to ETL job to edit the schema unless if you want to automate the process. You can use edit schema feature of data catalog generated by AWS Glue crawler.

- Navigate to tables of AWS Glue
- Choose the table you want to change schema
- you can find edit schema button inside the table

After editing the schema, you can see the versions of the table auto maintained by the AWS Glue

Furthermore, you can also compare the versions of the table

Comment: We are using Glue to perform a union on the multiple tables so that all the data is queryable from the same table so I believe that the ETL job is needed for that.
Additionally, I have tried to change the schema directly from the Glue console and have found that the data is no longer queryable from Athena due to schema changes not populating new fields with null values if they did not exist

Comment: Which data source are you using for the crawler? As per my understanding, I don't think you can modify schema of the crawled database using ETL job, correct me if i am wrong. The change in schema during the new crawling can be managed with crawler setting itself. You can configure crawler to update or delete the new changes during creation or edit the configuration after creation.